# SurveyMonkey Webhooks

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to register a webhook for SurveyMonkey. I can make other calls like list surveys etc to get the survey ids. But when i use those to call the register webhook i get the following message.

```
    {
  "error": {
    "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
    "message": "URL https://surveymonkey.com/webhook_reciever did not return a success status code. Status code was 301.",
    "id": "1000",
    "name": "Bad Request",
    "http_status_code": 400
  }
}
```

My input is this

```
    {
  "name": "My Webhook",
  "event_type": "response_completed",
  "object_type": "survey",
  "object_ids": ["83811649", "83827620"],
  "subscription_url": "https://surveymonkey.com/webhook_reciever"
    }
```

I assume that the object_ids are the survey ids. i also tried changing the subscription url but that did not help. anyone done this?

Answer (score 2):

It says the issue in the error message:

`URL https://surveymonkey.com/webhook_reciever did not return a success status code. Status code was 301.`

When you register a webhook, the SurveyMonkey servers ping (with a HEAD request) the subscription_url you provided to make sure it's reachable before successfully registering the webhook. It always expects a "2xx" status code to acknowledge the request.

In your case the HEAD request returned a 301 which is a Moved Permanently request. This makes sense, because you seem to have a test URL at surveymonkey.com, you need to set up a server that accepts a HEAD request on the same URL as your subscription URL and return a 200 status code then it should work fine.

You can generate a test URL to receive requests at https://requestb.in/ for testing purposes if you'd like.